# How can dictionaries and branches be used in Keras to predict multi-labels?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

**Below you will find the code as well as the error i encounter**

This is a Keras Sequential model with three branches at the end, each ending with a Dense layer with a different activation function:

1. The first branch, named "longitude", ends with a Dense layer with linear activation, which means that it will output a continuous value.
2. The second branch, named "floor", ends with a Dense layer with softmax activation, which means that it will output a probability distribution over five classes.
3. The third branch, named "userid", ends with a Dense layer with softmax activation, which means that it will output a probability distribution over 20 classes.

Define the model

```py
model = Sequential([
    Reshape((20, 26, 1), input_shape=(520,1)),
    Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(1, activation='linear', name='longitude'),
    Dense(5, activation='softmax', name='floor'),
    Dense(20, activation='softmax', name='userid')
])
model.summary()
```

model.summary() output

```py
Model: "sequential_15"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 reshape_15 (Reshape)        (None, 20, 26, 1)         0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_15 (Conv2D)          (None, 18, 24, 32)        320       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_15 (MaxPoolin  (None, 9, 12, 32)        0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 flatten_15 (Flatten)        (None, 3456)              0         
                                                                 
 longitude (Dense)           (None, 1)                 3457      
                                                                 
 floor (Dense)               (None, 5)                 10        
                                                                 
 userid (Dense)              (None, 20)                120       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 3,907
Trainable params: 3,907
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Compile model

```py
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', 
              loss={'floor': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
                    'userid': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
                    'longitude': 'mean_squared_error'}, 
              metrics={'floor': 'accuracy', 
                       'floor': 'accuracy', 
                       'longitude': 'mean_absolute_error'})
```

Train model

```py
model.fit(train_input, {'floor': train_output[:,1], 
                        'userid': train_output[:,0], 
                        'longitude': train_output[:,2]}, 
          epochs=10,
          validation_data=(val_input, {'floor': val_output[:,1], 
                                       'userid': val_output[:,0], 
                                       'longitude': val_output[:,2]}))
```

Despite working well with a single label, whenever I attempt to fit the model for multi-labels using dictionaries and branches, I consistently encounter the following error.

```py
Epoch 1/10

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-85-e87d65b1802f> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # Train model
----> 2 model.fit(train_input, {'floor': train_output[:,1], 
      3                         'userid': train_output[:,0],
      4                         'longitude': train_output[:,2]}, 
      5           epochs=10,

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1109, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 236, in __call__
        y_true = self._conform_to_outputs(y_pred, y_true)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 60, in _conform_to_outputs
        struct = map_to_output_names(outputs, self._output_names, struct)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 805, in map_to_output_names
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Found unexpected losses or metrics that do not correspond to any Model output: dict_keys(['floor', 'longitude']). Valid mode output names: ['userid']. Received struct is: {'floor': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None,) dtype=float32>, 'longitude': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2' shape=(None,) dtype=float32>}.
```

Comment: You cannot do a multi-output model with the Sequental API, only with the Functional API.

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Snoopy for your helpful contribution! Can you please post your answer so I can accept it?